# Getting ‘NO DEVICES FOUND: Press 'M' and '+' to add’ when running bfgminer

Tags: server, 18.04, bitcoin

Yesterday I installed bfgminer on my Ubuntu 18.04 VServer to mine Bitcoins...
I did this by cloning the github-repository (https://github.com/luke-jr/bfgminer) and installing the necessary dependencies. After that I ran `./autogen.sh` and `./configure —enable-cpumining` to mine with my cpu.
Finally I finished the installation with `make`.
After installing I tried to start bfgminer with the `./bfgminer`-command and got the following error:

```
NO DEVICES FOUND: Press 'M' and '+' to add
```

Could please help me with this problem?